# namedtuple in python syntax weird from built-in types and orderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary, namedtuple

this is my first question on stackoverflow. I just learnt the namedtuple and found sth weird.

When you want to initiate a namedtuple from an iterable, you have to either add a prefix * or use the _make method.

*for instance:*

```
City=namedtuple('city',['name','country','population','coordinates'])

delhi_data = ('Delhi NCR', 'IN', 21.935, LatLong(28.613889, 77.208889))

delhi = City(*('Delhi NCR', 'IN', 21.935, LatLong(28.613889, 77.208889)))
```

But when you initiate a tuple, dict or even orderedDict from the same collection package, you can just tuple() or dict() or orderedDict().

*for instance:*

```
from collections import OrderedDict

items = (
('A', 1),
('B', 2),
('C', 3)
)

regular_dict = dict(items)

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(items)
```

Why the syntax for namedtuple is so weird? Thanks!

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)

Comment: thanks for the reply! I expect sth similar, like City(delhi_data). So I dont need to add a prefix *

Comment: Are you asking what the `*` does, or why nametuple was designed to require it?

Comment: Exactly! why it is designed to have a * @BrenBarn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/PGWVm8ANbdE) about why namedtuple was designed this way.  The basic reason is that the "normal" way to create a namedtuple is with a call like `MyTupleClass(1, 2, 3)`, where the values are accepted as separate arguments.  If it accepted only one iterable argument (as `tuple` does), you would *have* to write `MyTupleClass((1, 2, 3))` with an extra set of parentheses (that is, `MyTupleClass(1, 2, 3)` would raise an error, as `tuple(1, 2, 3)` does).  It is true that this means you have to use an extra star (or use the `._make()` method) if initializing from an iterable, but this isn't any harder, it's just different.  The decision was apparently to make the simple case (initializing with literal values) easier, at the expense of making a more complex case (unpacking from an iterable) a bit different from a regular tuple.

Comment: Yes! Could I summarize your point like this: tuple take one argument and namedtuple take multi-argument accordingly, so the * just to unpack the item to match each argument in the nametuple.  Btw, the OrderedDict Object also take only one argument? Thanks!

Comment: I have just tried it out. The OrderDict get at most 1 argument like tuple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it behaves similarly to a dict:

```
from collections import namedtuple
MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', 'A B C')

items = (('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3))

my_tuple = MyTuple(**dict(items))
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! Sorry but I am now more confused. Why double ** here? I am new to python...

Comment: `**` says to map the key value pairs of the dict into the MyTuple constructor.  You should read the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters) that @DYZ left above

Comment: Thanks! But I think this would be a little deviating. Sorry didnt make it clear. My question is when to initiate instance with tuple(delhi_data and items in my example). Why namedtuple has to add a * but orderedDict does not? (City(*delhi_data) V.S. OrderedDict(items)). Thanks!